# Point limit for single answer

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting

I have search for the answer but I didn't find.

Just for a curiosity. Is there any limit for point gained for one correct answer? I have answered and I have 7 upvotes but only 50 points. The answer hasn't been accepted yet. Reputation earned today is 183 so I have still 17 left for today to 200 per daqy. Are there any other limits?

Comment: Try clicking on the today link after clicking on the envelope.  That might show you the actual correct total for the day.

Comment: You are right ;-) Sorry, I thought "Today" is default. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, there is **not** a point limit for a question or answer.

My guess is the envelope thing is not showing you the correct number for rep gained today.

Comment: Ding ding ding.

Comment: It should be noted that the only point limits come when you hit the daily reputation cap. Any votes while you are over the limit will not get counted, but once the day rolls over, you can start gaining rep on it again.